# Is the ++ operator more efficient than a=a+1?

Tags: java, increment

In Java, Is the increment operator more efficient that a simple addition operation?

Comment: Could you provide a source for that?

Comment: Post- or pre-incremental? The question should be rather starting with **Is** than with *Why*

Comment: More efficient? Which benchmark standard do you present to back that claim?

Comment: When will this ever be the bottleneck for any real program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>It compiles to the exact same byte code.</strike>  It's all a matter of preference.

**EDIT**:
As it turns out this is **NOT** true.

```
public class SO_Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        a++;
        a += 1;
        ++a;    
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Example:

```
public class SO_Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        a = a + 1;
        a++;
        a += 1;
        ++a;    
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

The differences can be analyzed on the [Java bytecode instruction listings page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).  In short, `a = a + 1` issues `iload_1`, `iconst_1`, `iadd` and `istore_1`, whereas the others only use `iinc`.

From @NPE:

> The prevailing philosophy is that javac deliberately chooses not to
>   optimize generated code, relying on the JIT compiler to do that at
>   runtime. The latter has far better information about the execution
>   environment (hardware architecture etc) as well as how the code is
>   being used at runtime.

So in conclusion, besides not compiling to the same byte code, with exceedingly high probability, it won't make a difference.  It's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: This is the answer needed. A small sample that displays the byte code generation so there's actually something to prove, and we're all done here.

Comment: Now, `++a` on the other hand...

Comment: And while you're at it, you should include `a += 1` which is slightly different under some circumstances.

Comment: @Slanec Can you elucidate that point

Comment: Since +1 has some extra instructions, does it mean on the very micro level ++ is fast than +1?

Answer (score 2):

It's not more efficient, it's just cleaner looking code.

Comment: Could you provide a source for that as well?